# Search Box disappears when I save Web Part Settings

Tags: web-part, list, 2013, search-box

I am checking the "display search box" option in my web part properties and clicking "ok" but the search box disappears. When I click "apply" it will show the search box, but it will disappear again when I navigate back to the page.

Any one know why or how to fix this?

Comment: Having same issue, Are you able to resolve this?

Comment: try the option i mentioned in the answer. let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://blogs.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=92) blog by Jennifer Mason, titled *SharePoint 2010, Office365: Why does my web part randomly disappear?!?*.

Cite:

> There is a trick you can use to get your web part back. Select the checkbox next to the web part and click on the option to close the web part. This will place the web part in the closed web parts gallery and you will be able to re-add the web part to the site. Once you close the web part it will be added to the Closed Web Parts gallery. The closed web parts gallery can be accessed by adding a new web part to the page. You will see it at the bottom of the menu (if you have any closed web parts on the page). You can select and add this web part back to the page and it will add the web part that was lost when you were editing the settings
>
> How can I make this not happen?
>
> So far the best thing I have come across that keeps this from
>   happening is to add the web parts to the page and save the page before
>   editing any of the web part settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option:

1) Navigate to Site Settings -> Manage Site Features -> SharePoint Server Publishing

2) Disable the SharePoint Server Publishing feature and try, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason is the SharePoint bug that you cannot have two search box in same page. so if you already have a webpart with search box, you won't be able to turn on the another one. I don't know when will they fix this issue but it's quite common.